# how can I compress an audio file to reduce the size? FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

how can I compress an audio file to reduce the size?
not video
not image
it's just an audio file, and then I'll save it in the database

Comment: Audio is typically compressed with an audio codec. These can be lossy or lossless, trading off quality and size. The best are computationally expensive, so it's best to capture the audio already compressed (e.g. specify AAC or Opus, etc) if possible.